# Inviting four people to dinner if one of them can be invited only if that person's two friends will be there as well

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**A woman has 9 friends and must invite 4 of them to a dinner. The question is divided in two parts;**

**a) How many choices does she have if one of her friends can't be together *simultaneously* with other two friends?**

For this part I did: $\displaystyle {9\choose 4} - {3\choose 3} {6\choose 1}$

*I found a lot of questions like this on the forum, so I hope I got this part right (but I'm not good with math, so I can't be sure).
My problem is the second part.*

**b) How many choices does she have if one of her friends won't accept the invite unless that person's two friends are at the dinner as well.**

*I'm not sure how can I model this.
I tried to list all the possibilities of this part.*

1. This person and his 2 friends are selected, so we have ${6 \choose 1}$ people left to choose.
2. If one of these two friends will not be there, this person will not go as well. So we have $2\cdot {7\choose 4}$ choices (times 2 because it's a case for each friend).
3. If both friends will not be at the party then this person will not be there as well so we have $\binom{6}{4}$ people left to select.

> Then I just sum all these 3 cases, but I feel like I am over counting the possibilities. Do I really need the third case?

Unfortunately, there is no answer for this question to check. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part $(a)$, I interpret the question as suppose person $A$ won't attendd if $B$ attend or $C$ attend, then

If $A$ attends, then we won't invite $B$ or $C$ and out of the remaining $6$ people, we get to choose $3$ of them.

If $A$ doesn't attend, then we get to choose any $4$ people out of the remaining $8$.

$$\binom63+\binom84.$$

For part $(b)$, again, consider the two cases,

If $A$ attends, then we must invite $B$ and $C$ and out of the remaining $6$ people, we get to choose $1$ of them.

If $A$ doesn't attend, then we get to choose any $4$ out of the remaining $8$.

$$\binom61+\binom84$$

Comment: Sorry, I had some issues translating the question. at a) Person A won't attend if B AND C attend simultaneously. So please if you can check the answer with the corrected question.

b) I think this part is right and you are correct, I am over counting possibilities there are just 2 cases

Comment: If the only condition that forbid $A$ from attending is $B$ and $C$ both attend simultaneously, then  we need to rule out that case and what you did is correct.